# Is there an $F \in L^2({\mathbb{T}})$ s,t $\hat{F} = 1/\sqrt{n}$ for $n \geq 1$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am unsure of where to start with this. Is it a matter of showing:

$$\int_{\mathbb{T}}|F(n)|^2\mathrm d\lambda < \infty$$

So must I derive $\hat{F} = 1/\sqrt{n}$ ? Or should I be using Bessel's inequality?

Comment: Ok, maybe you should give some more context. I bet that $L^2$ means $L^2(\mathbb T)$ and that $\hat{F}(n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb T} f(x) e^{-inx}\, dx, $ but you should spend a couple of words on that.

Comment: Yes you're right, editted.

Comment: Anyway, the key lies in the following identity (usually attributed to Parseval or to Plancherel): $$\int_{\mathbb T} |F(x)|^2\, dx = \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{F}(n)|^2.$$ Assume that a function with the given Fourier coefficients exists, apply this identity, what happens?

Comment: I get $$\int_{\mathbb{T}}|F(x)|^2\mathrm dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$ which shows $$\int_\mathbb{T}|F(x)|^2\mathrm dx = {\infty}$$ So there is no solution?

Comment: What do you think. If $\int_{\mathbb T} |F(x)|^2\, dx=\infty$, is it possible that $F\in L^2(\mathbb T)$?